# Boolean and Method

Tags: java

I am new to programming and for my class I have to write a method and program for the following:

`boolean allTheSame(double x, double y, double z)` returning the average of the arguments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // **METHOD**//

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter variable for x");
    double x = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter variable for y");
    double y = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter variable for z");
    double z = in.nextDouble();

    boolean allTheSame = boolean allTheSame(x, y, z);
    System.out.println(allTheSame);

}

    // **TEST PROGRAM** //
 public static boolean allTheSame(double x, double y, double z)
 {

     if (x == y && x == z)
        {
            return true;
        }

     else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }

}
```

Given the fact that I am new, how can I do this?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: I know, I'm very new to programming and as you can tell not very good at it

Comment: did you want to know something?

Comment: "allTheSame" sounds like it should return a boolean, like you have done. Why should it return an average of the arguments?

Comment: Btw, any time you have code like `if (something) { return true; } else { return false; }` you can just do `return something` instead. It's always a preferable form. So, in your case, just `return x == y && x == z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean allTheSame = allTheSame(x, y, z);
System.out.println(allTheSame);
```

You don't need to put `boolean` before you call the method.

Comment: @FahrenheitNinetyNine Great. In 10 minutes (when it allows you to accept answers), please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.